# PyTorch: Not being able to run my fit function

Tags: pytorch

I am using [this table btw](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fprofile%2FMohamed_El_Azzouzi2%2Fpublication%2F275349599%2Ffigure%2Fdownload%2Ftbl2%2FAS%3A391760950906883%401470414497156%2FCorrosion-rate-value-of-the-corrosion-of-mild-steel-in-HCl-1M-media-with-and-without.png&f=1&nofb=1)

```
input = np.array([
                  [[313, 1], #HCL
                   [323, 1],
                   [333, 1],
                   [343, 1]], 
                  [[313, 10e-3], #Ortho
                   [323, 10e-3],
                   [333, 10e-3],
                   [343, 10e-3]], 
                  [[313, 10e-3], #Para
                   [323, 10e-3],
                   [333, 10e-3],
                   [343, 10e-3]]
                  ], dtype='float32')   target = np.array([[[14.76, 16.42, 18.08, 23.41]],
                    [[5.87, 11.14, 13.20, 25.72]],
                    [[2.73, 4.42, 8.04, 13.68]]], dtype='float32') loss_fn = F.mse_loss loss = loss_fn(model(input), target)
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([3, 1, 4])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([3, 4, 4])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.


def fit(num_epochs, model, loss_fn, opt):
  for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for xb, yb in train_dl:
      pred = model(xb)
      loss = loss_fn(preds, yb)
      loss.backward()
      opt.step()
      opt.zero_grad()

    if (epoch+1) % 10 == 0:
      print('Epoch [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs, loss.item()))

fit(100, model, loss_fn, opt)
```

Output:

```
Epoch [10/100], Loss: 25.1053
Epoch [20/100], Loss: 25.1050
Epoch [30/100], Loss: 25.1047
Epoch [40/100], Loss: 25.1043
Epoch [50/100], Loss: 25.1040
Epoch [60/100], Loss: 25.1036
Epoch [70/100], Loss: 25.1033
Epoch [80/100], Loss: 25.1030
Epoch [90/100], Loss: 25.1026
Epoch [100/100], Loss: 25.1023

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([3, 1, 4])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([3, 4, 4])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  """
```

I'm wondering if the shape mismatching gives an error in the fit function. Also I would like some general tips on how to make these matrices. So I don't run into this, maybe like a general rule of thumb. Or things I can do when I do run into this problem, because I don't wanna not be able to do anything once this happens.

EDIT: I fixed the error while in the `fit` function. But the warning persists. I am not sure what to do, because this gives very wrong data.

Comment: what is your loss_fn() defined as?

Comment: ```loss_fn = F.mse_loss```

```loss = loss_fn(model(input), target)```

Comment: What is ```F.mse_loss```?   but anyway, in ```loss = loss_fn(yb)``` you're missing the ```target``` parameter.

Comment: That is from ```torch.utilis.functional as F```

Comment: I understand thanks so much. I fixed it.

Comment: the ```loss_fn``` warning output is still there. And the predictions are giving out the wrong things.

Comment: Please update your post with your fix and the updated warning/error.

Comment: I edited it it turns out I didn't send the previous comment because it didn't reach to minimum character requirements